# how to only update specific fields and leave others with the previous values in findandupdate with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created an update function using Mongoose. However whenever I update the data using findOneAndUpdate. It updates only the fields entered and making it so that the others are now null or empty. I would like it so that when the user is updating and they dont update a filed it should remain as what it was before instead of being empty now. essentially only update the fields entered.

heres my routes

```
router.post("/updateStock", (req, res) => {
    const filter = {prodId: req.body.prodID}

    const update = req.body

    Product.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {new: true}).then((product) => {
        console.log("success");
        res.send(product);
  }).catch(err => {
       console.log("err", err);
       res.status(500).send(err);
  })

});
```

here's an example of req.body.
I've only updated the title and catergory on the frotnend meaning everything else is blank. When it saves in the DB it ony updates the title and catergory and leaves everything else blank. I would like it to not insert the blank ones into the DB and leave the fields as they are

```
{
  prodId: 'iPhone 111001200',
  title: 'iPhone 11 Pro',
  manufacturer: '',
  catergory: 'Electronics',
  price: '',
  quantity: ''
}
```

Here's my model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Product = mongoose.model(
  "Product",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    manufacturer: String,
    price: String,
    catergory: String,
    quantity: String,
    prodID: String, 
    images: Array
  })
);

module.exports = Product;
```

Comment: On the update part, use [`$set`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) to define the fields you want to update

Comment: like {$set: update}, I tried using that but no luck

Comment: {$set: {age: 7, size: 9}}

Comment: but I want to set the specific details the user enters on the frontend so it could change everytime

Comment: Sure this is only an example.

Comment: Please provide an example of req.body and example of the document that you want to update

Comment: @nimrodserok I've updated the question to show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this then:

```
const update = {};
for (const key of Object.keys(req.body)){
    if (req.body[key] !== '') {
        update[key] = req.body[key];
    }
}
test.findOneAndUpdate(filter, {$set: update}, {new: true}).then((product) => {
        console.log("success");
        res.send(product);
  }).catch(err => {
       console.log("err", err);
       res.status(500).send(err);
  })}
```

You should use the `$set` only to update the fields that you want to update. In your case, the fields that are not `''`.

Comment: such an elegant solution. thanks nimrod.

Comment: one would say that there is some built-in approach inside the mongodb driver to this, but no

Answer (score 0):

This function converts your payload into mongoose update query

```js
    function convertObject(obj, parentKey = '') {
  // Create an empty result object
  const result = {};

  // Iterate over the keys of the original object
  for (const key in obj) {
    // Check if the value is an object
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      // Call the function recursively to convert the nested object
      // Pass the parent key as an argument to append it to the nested keys
      Object.assign(result, convertObject(obj[key], `${parentKey ? `${parentKey}.` : ''}${key}`));
    } else {
      // Add the key to the result object with the same value
      // Use the parent key to create the full key in the format key1.key2.key3...
      result[`${parentKey ? `${parentKey}.` : ''}${key}`] = obj[key];
    }
  }

  // Return the result object
  return result;
}

// Test the function
const originalObject = { doc: { sub_doc: { nested_doc: 'text' } } };
console.log(convertObject(originalObject));
// Output: { 'doc.sub_doc.nested_doc': 'text' }
```